# Experimental design/test for 3 independent variables and 1-2 qualitative dependent variables?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, multiple-regression, multivariate-analysis, experiment-design, multiple-comparisons

Say I have a dataset containing `age`, `gender`, `race`, `selected field of study`, and `selected competence level in selected field` of 15,000 people.

I wish to see how and if age, gender, and/or race (and the interactions between these variables) influence the selected field of study and competence level.

I was thinking maybe I could use a 2-way ANOVA, but I believe ANOVA would not be applicable here since there are 3 independent variables (age, gender, race) and 2 dependent variables which are qualitative (categorical). So, I am not sure what do to.

Answer (score 0):

Usually in designs like yours where you would use multiple categorical predictor variables with a categorical DV (dependent variable) you would indeed not go for ANOVA (since this requires a higher measurement level for your dependent variable), but **'loglinear analysis'** instead is commonly used for this and will be appropriate here.
Hope this helps and good luck with your research!

Comment: Note that there are *two* categorical dependent variables.